# Why aren't my <a> elements centered within my <li> navigation elements?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, centering, nav

I am creating a website using a mobile-first approach. I am currently styling the navigation bar, which is comprised of a `ul` with five `li` elements and an `a` element within each `li`. For the mobile layout, I want the navigation to be perfectly centered. The `nav` element and the `li` elements appear to be perfectly centered; however, the `a` elements are not centered within each `li`... They are skewed toward the right. How can I correct this?

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="programs.html">Programs</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="why.html">Why</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
nav {
    width: 15%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}

nav ul {
     list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And here is an image of what the `nav` currently looks like in the browser (Chrome):

[image: an image of a vertical set of navigation buttons wherein the text inside each button is centered improperly]

Comment: can you please provide a JSfiddle that recreates your image with the issue so the community can better assist you?

Comment: Try removing width: 100% from both li and a.

Comment: Maybe is the margin for the tag `a`, try with `margin: 0`, and `text-aling: center`

Comment: I think you're missing giving some of the CSS information that's causing this issue.  As mentioned, providing a JSFiddle would help, but I would suspect it might be an issue with default browser styles.  Are you using something like Normalize.css?  http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/  You're using Chrome so press "F12" and use the Chrome Developer tool to select the element and inspect the CSS styles to find out what is causing that extra styling.

Answer (score 1):

Set the li's `margin` and `padding` to 0;

Answer (score 0):

Add the following inline or in an external style sheet to `nav a`

```
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
nav ul {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
  }

nav a {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     color: inherit;
     text-decoration: none;
     overflow: hidden;
     }
```

And use max-width on the  tag not simple width